# Keeping index compact and synced on dinamically generated input in jquery

Tags: jquery

I got a form with a "reapeatable" section (in a wordpress plugin option page), the section contains a couple of text input and a block of checkbox (this is the generated code):

```
From:
<input type="text" id="from-0" size="20" name="plugin_options_time[from][0]" value="12" />
To:
<input type="text" id="to-0" size="20" name="plugin_options_time[to][0]" value="15" />
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="plugin_options_time[mon][0]" value="1"></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="plugin_options_time[tue][0]" value="1"></li>
  ...
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="plugin_options_time[sun][0]" value="1"></li>
</ul>
```

Every section have a "Remove" button and at the end there is a "Add new button"
Using jQuery, every time i add a new section o remove on i run a function that reset the counter values in all field to have the correct sequence with no gap.
Basically the function will query the dom for a specific field, reset its name to a standar one, then it loops it and set back the index, for the from field is something like:

```
var inputfrom = $("input[name^='plugin_options_time[from]']").attr(
      'name',
      'from'
    ); //set all the from name to 'from'

$.each(inputfrom, function (index, value) {
      $(value)
        .attr('name', 'plugin_options_time[from][' + index + ']')
        .prop('id', 'from-' + index + '');
    }); //reassign the correct id
```

now I'm facing the checkboxes, they are 7 for each block named like plugin_options_time[DAY][INDEX], and I would like to avoid to grab the seven items and loop each one i was thinking something like grabbing all checkboxes rename them with the DAY part of the old name and then rename them again with the correct index, reducing the each from seven to two.

I'm wondering, how can i access the DAY part of the name? should i use a regex? if yes, how is the performance going?

Answer (score 1):

Since the index is the only number in the attribute, matching numbers and replacing with the desired input should do the trick:

```js
const indexToSet = 5;
const attr = "plugin_options_time[sun][0]";
console.log(
  attr.replace(/\d+/, indexToSet)
);
```

```
const newName = $(value).attr('name').replace(/\d+/, index);
$(value)
  .attr('name', newName)
  .prop('id', 'from-' + index + '');
```

> if yes, how is the performance going?

Since the number of elements being iterated over isn't unreasonably huge, the performance impact will be completely insignificant and unnoticeable.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this way:

```
var inputmon = $("li input[type='checkbox']"); //GET ALL THE CHECKBOXES
    $.each(inputmon, function (index, value) { //LOOP THEM AND RENAME WITH ONLY ITS DAY
      var name = $(value).attr('name');
      var res = name.split('[');
      var day = res[1].slice(0, -1);
      $(value).attr('name', day);
    });
    var idx = 0;
    $.each(inputmon, function (index, value) { //LOOP AGAIN TO FIX THE INDEX
      var day = $(value).attr('name');
      if (index % 7 == 0) { //I'M PRETTY SURE DAY OF WEEK ARE SEVEN
        idx = idx + 1;
      }
      $(value).attr(
        'name',
        'plugin_options_time[' + day + '][' + (idx - 1) + ']'
      );
    });
```

This code is inside a function called everytime a block is added or removed to the DOM so that when posting and saving as wordpress option there are no gaps between indexes
Any suggestion from improvement will be appreciated!